# Constrained optimization where the constraint is computed as a part of objective function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I made a function `f` that takes a long time to run. The constraints are calculated at the end of `f`'s routine. How can I return these constraints to cobyla without evaluating `f` twice?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin_cobyla as mini
def f(x, returncons=True):
    if returncons: return x[1] - x[0]
    else: return (x[0] - 2)**2 + 4 * (x[1] -x[0]**2)**2

x_opt = mini(f, [1., 1.], args=(False,), cons=f)
```

Comment: Have you considered saving the constraints calculated by `f` and then using the saved value?

Comment: Perhaps use `functools.lru_cache`? Don't know how much overhead that adds, though.

Comment: @JakobLovern Yes that is what I want to do. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### LRU Cache

This is implementing Paul Panzer's suggestion, it relies on [@lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) which is a Python 3 feature. We cannot directly apply this decorator to the objective function, because it receives a NumPy array, which is mutable and therefore not hashable. So we need two functions:

- `func_with_cons` computes the objective and constraint, given scalar arguments.
- `f` calls `func_with_cons` and returns either objective or constraint, based on `returncons` argument.

Note that we need `consargs` parameter in the call to `fmin_cobyla`, because without it the same extra arguments `args` will be passed to the constraint function.

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin_cobyla as mini
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def func_with_cons(x0, x1):
    return (x0 - 2)**2 + 4 * (x1 -x0**2)**2, x0 - x1

def f(x, returncons=True):
    value, cons = func_with_cons(x[0], x[1])
    return cons if returncons else value

func_with_cons.cache_clear()
x_opt = mini(f, (1., 1.), cons=f, args=(False,), consargs=())
print(x_opt)
print(func_with_cons.cache_info())
```

Output:

```
[ 1.14491021  1.14491021]
CacheInfo(hits=41, misses=32, maxsize=32, currsize=32)
```

So, the cache works. I changed the constraint from x1-x0 to x0-x1 to show that it also works (the original constraint x1-x0 is satisfied by the global minimum of this function, so it would have no effect on the result).

Cache size can be much smaller: with `maxsize=2` we would have 40 hits (vs 41 with the above size).

#### Global variable

This is implementing Jakob Lovern's suggestion. The function f stores the constraint in a global variable, from which the function cons retrieves it. The use of a global has obvious drawbacks, but then again, this works in Python 2.7.

```
def f(x):
    global stored_cons
    stored_cons = x[0] - x[1]
    return (x[0] - 2)**2 + 4 * (x[1] -x[0]**2)**2

def cons(x):
    return stored_cons

x0 = [1., 1.] 
f(x0)  # called to initialize stored_cons        
x_opt = mini(f, x0, cons=cons)
```

This returns `[ 1.14491021,  1.14491021]` since the global minimum [2, 4] is disallowed by the constraint.

Comment: I don't think this translates to a real workflow. What if my function is imported from another program?

Comment: I added a version with `lru_cache`